# Using SQL Server specific code in Access linked to SQL Server database

Tags: ms-access, sql-server

I have an access file that is linked (through an ODBC connection) to a SQL Server 2008 database. I am trying to write some reports against this database. However, Access chokes when I write the select query of the report with SQL syntax specific to SQL Server that doesn't exist in access. Shouldn't this work, since it's the SQL Server engine running the queries and just sending the data back to Access to display? Is there any way to get this to work?

Need this to work on any combination of Access 2007 and 2010, and SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

**Edit**
Note: I cannot create a SQL Server stored procedure or function, or otherwise modify the original (SQL Server) schema in any way.

Comment: @Brennan don't forget to mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: I need to use a "pass-through query".

Comment: No, you don't need to. You can write Jet/ACE-specific SQL and Jet/ACE will convert it into something the ODBC driver can translate into SQL Server syntax. Now, if you're trying to use CASE SELECT or something like that in your SQL, that's different, but likely you don't need the SQL Server-specific syntax at all -- you should learn the Jet/ACE equivalent and use that and then you wouldn't have to use a passthrough at all.