# Trying to run a SQL update query in MS Access using VBA, not sure if aliases are allowed

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need help with this query I am trying to write with in VBA in MS Access:

```
  Dim sqlstring as String
  UPDATE t1 " _
  & " SET [problemID] = t2.[problemID] " _
  & " FROM dbo.table1 t1 " _
     & " JOIN dbo.table2 t2 " _
        & " ON t1.[problemDescription] = t2.[problemDescription]
  DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlstring)
```

What I would like to happen is, when this runs, table1 will fill the values in its column, `problemID`, with the number associated with the values in its column `problemDescription` that match the values in the column `problemDescription` in `table2`. table2 has a `problemID` column as well and this column has values in it that I need passed to table1, if all that makes sense.

Whenever it runs, I get a syntax error saying there is a missing operator in the expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SQL Server specific code in Access linked to SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933487/using-sql-server-specific-code-in-access-linked-to-sql-server-database)

Comment: Is the SQL-Server tag needed?

Answer (score 0):

In Access your SQL syntax is wrong (and you've missed the opening `"` before `UPDATE`.

You've written your query as:

```
  UPDATE t1 
  SET [problemID] = t2.[problemID]
  FROM dbo.table1 t1 JOIN dbo.table2 t2
      ON t1.[problemDescription] = t2.[problemDescription]
```

Access syntax is:

```
  UPDATE Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ProblemDescription = T2.ProblemDescription
  SET    T1.ProblemID = T2.ProblemID
```

Having said that, if you're using a pass-through query you have to use the syntax of the database being used (SQL-Server in this case I guess).

Answer (score 0):

No. Field and table names must be fixed.

You need, in VBA, the (re)build the `sqlstring` replacing the placeholders with the actual and literal field names.

Then run the SQL.